# T4 Template containing XML results in parse errors

Tags: .net, xml, config, t4, transformation

I have created T4 Templates for the config files of my web and windows projects. I can successfully generate master web.config, and all configs for other environments, i.e. web.ci.config, etc..However, I could not get rid of the errors on my master tt files, such as :

> - Character '#', hexadecimal value 0x23 is illegal in an XML name.
> - Character '<', hexadecimal value 0x3c is illegal in XML attribute values.
> - Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it.

I should be missing a xml schema or a reference, but what?

---

My file looks like:

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostSpecific="true" #>
<#@ output extension= ".config" #>  
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
...  
    <add key="FileUploadFolder" value="<#= this.FileUpload #>" /> 
...
</configuration>
<#+ 
   string FileUpload="\\\\server\\folder";
#>
```

And here is [screenshot](http://continuousdevelopment.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/web-tt.png)

Comment: I think the problem might be that a .tt file is parsed to XML, and is getting confused by your XML content.  Out of interest - what happens if you set the `output extension` to `.xml` ?

Comment: Yes, probably but all the example screenshots I see on the net are without errors [the red underline]. 
When I set to `.xml`, it creates exactly the same [and expected] document as it does for the `.config` output.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [Visual Studio 2012 T4 templates generating XML gives error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12259217/1380680), which has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Same problem here. I worked around it by replacing in the `.tt` file the line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

with

```
<# WriteLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"); #>
```

Once VS is confused about the XML format of the template file, it seems to persist in that confusion -- even after editing like above and a restart. The only way around that seems to be to delete the existing `.tt` file from your project and re-create it from scratch.

With this change, the `.tt` file does not have a `<?xml?>` tag anymore so VS does not consider it an XML file. It ignores everything inside the literal string. Your whole template now looks like this:

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostSpecific="true" #>
<#@ output extension= ".config" #>  
<# WriteLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"); #>
<configuration>
...  
    <add key="FileUploadFolder" value="<#= this.FileUpload #>" /> 
...
</configuration>
<#+ 
    string FileUpload="\\\\server\\folder";
#>
```

Comment: Nope, it did not work. My problem is not with the output, the config file is generated perfectly. The problem is when I open the tt file in VS IDE, from the first line it starts underlining the characters

Comment: I've added the [screenshot](http://continuousdevelopment.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/web-tt.png)

Comment: The screenshot you added does not show the change I suggested. The third line should be replaced with the `<# Writeline... #>` as shown above. Don't forget to try this from scratch, with a new `.tt` file, otherwise VS remains confused.

Comment: I understand your confusion now, you should not make this change in the output, but in the template itself. I will edit the answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: @DotNetWise Did you check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12259217/1380680)? It is about VS2012 and the answer was accepted.

Comment: The problem is not at the beginning but rather at the end. In my case the xml file I want to output is a .nuspec file.

http://screencast.com/t/b5X4FebyLzfk

If you remove T4's <#+ thing at the end it will trow an even bigger error and T4 will fail at all

Comment: @DotNetWise: Can you post your whole template file, not just the last snippet? Although the problem reveals itself at the end of the file, the cause is at the beginning. Because it has `<?xml` there, VS will interpret is as XML and emit the errors you are suffering from. If that `<?xml` is removed, then the file will not be interpreted as XML anymore, and your errors should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that the Xml language service in VS is mistakenly identifying your T4 file as an Xml file, so spewing lots of false positive error messages.

I'm looking into whether there's a workaround to force it to ignore T4 files.
If you could log a bug on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio), that would be helpful.

Comment: Check out my answer for the workaround that I used -- could save you some time.

Comment: Yep, Reinier's workaround appears to be the best available at present.